# ASMACK. Create new user and add to a specific group

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I want to register as new users to the xmpp server (Openfire) through the android client and all the new users must be communicated. I create the users, but I'm not sure how to add these to the roster entries to start to talk. I dont know if its better to create a group and add all contacts, but I neither know how to do it.

```
    try {
        con.connect();

        AccountManager am = con.getAccountManager();

        am.createAccount(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        Log.i(TAG,"Creation complete");
    }
    catch (XMPPException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error at user creation "+e);
        return false;

    }
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to attain this... Any help will be grately appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 1):

You add contacts to your roster by sending presence packets. See section "**Adding Entries to the Roster**" on http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/roster.html

And then you can add them to a Roster group: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/RosterGroup.html

Comment: I had already saw that, but how can I know users in wich send Entry? I need that all new  user can communicate with another. Has Roster Listener some registration event?